# Transfer function gas limit, why 2,300?

Tags: solidity, gas, bytecode

I read in the literature that the limit for a Solidity transfer function is 2,300 gas units, because it prevents possible threats like reentrancy, etc.

However, I cannot understand **why** *exactly* 2,300 gas units are used. In my understanding, the dangerous instructions are `SSTORE`(that costs 20000 or 5000 gas units), `SELFDESTRUCT` (5000) and the different `CALLS` instructions (e.g., the `CALL` instruction requires 700 gas units + cost for each provided argument).

I did not find a (mathematical) justification for this imposed limit.

Comment: this value was empirically found during a long history of spam attacks

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is valid and Ethereum Improvement Proposal(EIP) is created regarding the same.

You can track it using the following link-

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1285

Comment: Thank you for the reference, do you have any idea about the rational for the gas limit of 2,300 gas?

Comment: The only rationale I know is to avoid reentrancy attack.